# Mobile jQuery in ios - how to get element position in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, position, element

I first used jQuery-Mobile and I don't know how to use in ios my project.

Which file must i import? In http://jquerymobile.com/ site, i downloaded jquery.mobile-1.0b3.js and jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js. which i use?

This is my code.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jquery.mobile-1.0b3" ofType:@"js"];
NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];
```

Is this right?

And i want to get specified element. In jquery, there is a function - '.position'
But mobile jquery support this function? How can i?

```
NSString *code = @"var p=$('p:first'); var pos=p.position();"
NSLog(@"%@", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"position.left"]);
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit that I do not know how to use PhoneGap or UIWebView yet, but... Here is how you use jquery and jquery mobile to get the positions if it were a regular web page.

I could be misunderstanding you but you seem to be under the impression that the jquery mobile JS is either a substitute for or includes the base level jquery library.  This is not the case.  To make jquery mobile work **you need the base level jquery library first**. The head of any jquery mobile page include the following...

```
jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css
jquery-1.6.4.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js
```

Once you have those assets in the page, you can find the position of an element like this...

```
var position = $("#idOfElementOrSomeOtherSelector").position();
alert("the element is at top: "+position.top+" left: "+position.left );
```

I'm not sure how this changes with PhoneGap but with any luck, this should give you a clue.